# Sending emails without user interaction - authentication issue

Tags: android

im trying to send an email from my app without the user having to confirm. I' ve had some success with the winning answer from this post: [sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-android-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-android-app)
However, this requires to put the email password into the code itself. I'd rather not do this for security reasons. Also I dont want to ask the users for their passwords. That would probably confuse them. (i would get sceptical if an app would aks me for my gmail pass)

Is there any way to avoid having to specify the sending password, maybe by using AccountManager to authenticate with the phone's gmail account?

Or, how would i go about enctypting the password if i chose to use my own?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to send emails without prompting the user or having the user provide their credentials then you are going to need to provide the credentials yourself.  As far as hiding the password string you can consider doing something like this: [hiding strings in Obfuscated code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427238/hiding-strings-in-obfuscated-code)