# How to encrypt server URL in android?

Tags: android, url, encryption

Hi I am working with android.I had created a library project in which data fetched from my server.Now I need to provide my library project to a third party developer, So How can I encrypt my server URL to others??

Comment: possible duplicate of [hiding strings in Obfuscated code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427238/hiding-strings-in-obfuscated-code)

Comment: If you're relying on a hidden URL to protect your service, you're screwed.  First, there is no way that you can protect it enough that they can't get around it-  if nothing else they can catch the DNS queries leaving the device.  Secondly, any other user who accidentally finds your URL, such as a portscanner or spider will screw you over.

Comment: @GabeSechan agreed with u r point

Answer (score 0):

Try this way :

```
String stringThatNeedsToBeEncrpyted = "PutYourURL"; 
        MessageDigest mdEnc = null;
        try {
            mdEnc = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } // Encryption algorithm
        mdEnc.update(stringThatNeedsToBeEncrpyted.getBytes(), 0, stringThatNeedsToBeEncrpyted.length());
        String md5 = new BigInteger(1, mdEnc.digest()).toString(16); 
        System.out.println(md5);
```

Comment: I created encrypted url in a separate project , Now can i used it instead of my original url in my original project ? is it wrks?? or need of encryption in the same project ??

Answer (score 0):

I think even you encrypt your URL with des and then decrypt it to connect to your server,as your **source code** is provided to others,then can see it clearly because then can debug your code.

Answer (score 0):

I think , SHA-512 OR BCRYPT  is the best mechanism for hashing to prevent hacking from hackers.
        please follow one of them.