# Convert java.lang.Byte[] to string in Java

Tags: java, string, java-native-interface, arrays

i am getting java.lang.Byte[] from c(jbyteArray in JNI) . How to convert this jbyteArray to string in java.

c function is

```
jbyteArray Java_eu_ratikal_helloc_MainActivity_getNameBytes(JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz) {


    int n=0;
    jstring na ="HelloAndroidString";
    char* p = "HelloAndroidString";
    while(*p++){
        n++;
    }
    jbyteArray arr = (*env)->NewByteArray(env, n);
    (*env)->SetByteArrayRegion(env,arr,0,n, (jbyte*)na);

    char* b = (char*)arr;
    return arr;
}
```

java code is

```
byte[] bytes = getNameBytes();
```

Getting compilation error like

Incompatible types
Required byte[]
Found java.lang.Byte[]

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String(byte[])

Comment: make use of java.util.Arrays.toString(bye[])

Comment: Do you mean `new String(bytes, "UTF-8")`?

Comment: @PeterLawrey I cannot use this because java.lang.Byte[] is different from bytes[]

Comment: @PrabhuM There is no sane reason to use a `Byte[]` It uses 4x as much memory, is slower, and much harder to work with in JNI.  btw `jbyteArray` is `byte[]` not a `Byte[]`

Comment: @PeterLawrey I have edited my  question. please check

Comment: Have you defined `public native byte[] getNameBytes();` ? Or did you use `Byte[]` ?

Comment: @PeterLawrey , I used public native Byte[] getNameBytes();  Now changed to byte[] and working fine. Please mention the same thing  as answer I will mark it as accepted. Thanks. Also can u please answer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35573832/obfuscating-or-hiding-strings-in-c-file-in-android-apk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return

```
public native byte[] getNamBytes();
```

but to convert it into a String you need to use `new String` e.g.

```
public String String getName() {
    return new String(getNameBytes(), "UTF-8");
}
```

Comment: Can u please tell me hoe to hide or obfuscate string in c file while using ndk

Comment: @PrabhuM what are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to secure api urls and keys from reverse engineering of android apk file. So I am trying to keep these things in c file and then access in java using ndk. But  even in C file(.so file) strings are easily readable after reverse engineering

Comment: @PrabhuM so you need to encypt them.  If you are going to encypt them, I would do that in Java, but that's because I am a Java programmer, not a C programmer.

Comment: @PrabhuM btw no matter what you do, the strings will have to be readable at runtime, which means if I modify your program I could get it to log out these strings.  The URLs are also visible to anyone sniffing the network without modifying your program.

Comment: But how to secure auth keys then?

Comment: @PrabhuM One way is to have the server send a challenge-response.  The server sends a string, the code has to transform it and give the appropriate response.  This way, the auth key needed each time is different, and not actually stored anywhere.