# how make url string complicated

Tags: java, android

Creating an android app to receive data in json format from web server 
in my app I should have url as string and use it to fetch data like below

```
private static final String my_url = "http://example.com/folder/showJsonData.php";
jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, my_url ,new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
.
.
.
}
```

as you see my_url is not complicated or encoded so everyone can access it after decompiling apk.
the question is that how can I make it a little more complicated 
please explain it with example.
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [hiding strings in Obfuscated code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427238/hiding-strings-in-obfuscated-code)

Answer (score 0):

URL encoding is done in the same way on android as in Java SE;

```
try {
    String url = "http://www.example.com/?id=123&art=abc";
    String encodedurl = URLEncoder.encode(url,"UTF-8");
    Log.d("TEST", encodedurl);
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: but String url is still there! you are just encoding that. if anyone decompile the app will see that line of code

Comment: you can save url into your DB, that will help you for sure.