# Hiding String using Proguard

Tags: java, android, json, android-proguard

I have a String Array in my MainActivity Class.

[image]

I want to hide this string array from my java file. I have used proguard to secure my app but when i export my app and decompile it,it's become very easy to get my string value.Proguard is just changing my value name not hiding the string.see the screenshot below.
[image]
Now i want to hide my url string from my java file. I don't know how can i do that.so please help me to hide this string.

**Proguard.cfg**

```
-keep class com.google.android.gms.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
```

**Project-properties**

```
target=android-21
android.library.reference.1=..\\google-play-services_lib
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard.cfg
```

I am using **Eclipse**.Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you plan to hide this? If the value is used in the app, it has to be inside the compiled classes in some readable form.

Comment: i want to hide or encrypt the sting.

Comment: I know. Why do you think that's possible?

Comment: then how other android application are hiding their important link from their application? i searched google and know that it's possible to hide string.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427238/hiding-strings-in-obfuscated-code

Comment: @RicardoBarroca i see the answere before but i don't understand it.

Comment: You need to create a key in keyStore or add one manually (keystore is better), encrypt your strings manually with it, store the encrypted strings in your array and then use the decryption method to retrieve them. Is this more clear to you?

Comment: I have `String url[] = {"hello " , "world" };` array then what should i do. Give me the **code** please @RicardoBarroca