# How to make a static string into binary when an app compiles

Tags: android, reverse-engineering

I'm trying to secure my app and a few strings inside it so that people dont decompile it and make it their own (it has happened to me 3 times already)

what i'm trying to do is convert one string that has the link to my json file into binary when the app is compiled....currently its just a static field...

whenever i decompile my own app it shows the url path to my json file in the decompiled files...is there any thing i can do to protect this one line of code and still have it work properly?

Comment: If you are talking about "obfuscating" your string(s), you can check responses in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427238/hiding-strings-in-obfuscated-code

Comment: A reasonable percentage of the people who can decompile your app will also be able to reverse the changes that you make to the string. Or, they will just get the value from a traffic monitor.