# How to secure the server URLs in Android application

Tags: android, android-security

I have designed an android application where I am communicating with my company's server. Now I am planning to release my Application in Playstore But, I need to secure my server URL's in Android Application. Is there anyway? Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by Secure?

Comment: see the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427238/hiding-strings-in-obfuscated-code

Comment: Why do you want to secure the URL? Do you have something illegal to hide?

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to disappear your URLs because packets can capture in Android, so you need to secure your APIs by available solutions like SSL, Certificate pinning, OTP, AccessToken,...